# IMX6 ADV7180 : no /dev/media0

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, graphics, video-encoding

I am using kernel 4.14.24 from kernel.org on a KARO-TX6Q and an ADV7182 on a custom board.

With the kernel 4.1.15 from KARO git, I used the adv7180_tvin driver modified to  work with adv7182. This driver does not use the media_controller system and directly creates a /dev/videoX entry.

Since a new software update, the 4.1.15 kernel is too old. I need to use the 4.14.24 kernel from kernel.org.

In kernel.org adv7180_tvin does not exist and I have to use the media_controller binding system.

**Kernel opts :**

```
CONFIG_MEDIA_CONTROLLER=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2_SUBDEV_API=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_MUX=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_CODA=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_MEM2MEM_DEINTERLACE=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_SH_VEU=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_ADV7180=m
CONFIG_IMX_IPUV3_CORE=y
CONFIG_IMX_HAVE_PLATFORM_IPU_CORE=y
```

**Boot log :**

```
[    3.468290] imx-media capture-subsystem: Media device initialized
[    3.474664] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added port, match type FWNODE
[    3.483815] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added ipu1_csi0_mux, match type FWNODE
[    3.493779] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added camera, match type FWNODE
[    3.503180] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added port, match type FWNODE
[    3.512311] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added port, match type FWNODE
[    3.521454] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added port, match type FWNODE
[    3.530520] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added ipu2_csi1_mux, match type FWNODE
[    3.541128] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-vdic.2, match type DEVNAME
[    3.551657] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-ic.3, match type DEVNAME
[    3.561998] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-ic.4, match type DEVNAME
[    3.572307] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-ic.5, match type DEVNAME
[    3.582649] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-vdic.8, match type DEVNAME
[    3.593245] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-ic.9, match type DEVNAME
[    3.603684] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-ic.10, match type DEVNAME
[    3.603994] imx-media capture-subsystem: imx_media_add_async_subdev: added imx-ipuv3-ic.11, match type DEVNAME
[    3.604921] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu1_vdic
[    3.605717] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu2_vdic
[    3.606199] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu1_ic_prp
[    3.606447] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu1_ic_prpenc
[    3.608277] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu1_ic_prpvf
[    3.609036] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu2_ic_prp
[    3.609254] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu2_ic_prpenc
[    3.610069] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu2_ic_prpvf
[    3.611536] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu1_csi0
[    3.612867] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu1_csi1
[    3.821930] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu1_csi0_mux
[    3.822390] imx-media: Registered subdev ipu2_csi1_mux
[   14.911115] imx-media: Registered subdev adv7180 1-0020
[   14.931374] imx-media capture-subsystem: Entity type for entity adv7180 1-0020 was not initialized!
```

**DTB file :**

```
&i2c2 {
    pinctrl-names = "default", "gpio";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c2>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&pinctrl_i2c2_gpio>;
    scl-gpios = <&gpio2 30 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    sda-gpios = <&gpio3 16 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    status = "okay";

    adv7182: camera@20 {
        compatible = "adi,adv7182";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        /* pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_adv7182>; */
        reg = <0x20>;
        powerdown-gpios = <&gpio3 17 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio1>;
        interrupts = <27 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;

        port {
            adv7182_to_ipu1_csi0_mux: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&ipu1_csi0_mux_from_parallel_sensor>;
                bus-width = <8>;
            };
        };
    };
};

&ipu1_csi0_from_ipu1_csi0_mux {
    bus-width = <8>;
};

&ipu1_csi0_mux_from_parallel_sensor {
    remote-endpoint = <&adv7182_to_ipu1_csi0_mux>;
    bus-width = <8>;
};

&ipu1_csi0 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ipu1_csi0>;
};


pinctrl_ipu1_csi0: ipu1_csi0grp {
    fsl,pins = <
    MX6QDL_PAD_CSI0_PIXCLK__IPU1_CSI0_PIXCLK    0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_CSI0_VSYNC__IPU1_CSI0_VSYNC      0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_CSI0_MCLK__IPU1_CSI0_HSYNC       0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT12__IPU1_DISP0_DATA12   0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT13__IPU1_DISP0_DATA13   0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT14__IPU1_DISP0_DATA14   0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT15__IPU1_DISP0_DATA15   0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT16__IPU1_DISP0_DATA16   0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT17__IPU1_DISP0_DATA17   0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT18__IPU1_DISP0_DATA18   0x10
    MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT19__IPU1_DISP0_DATA19   0x10
    >;
};
```

There is no /dev/media0 file.
How can I debug?

Thanks

**Edit :**

This line is never called because list_empty(&notifier->waiting) is always false. [drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-async.c @126](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.14/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-async.c#L126)

```
if (list_empty(&notifier->waiting) && notifier->complete)
    return notifier->complete(notifier); // <-- this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media controller needs to have both two IPU activated.
Solved by adding in dts :

```
&ipu2 {
        status = "okay";
};
```